# $A\subset B$ with non empty resolvent sets $\implies A=B$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I read this statement on my notes and I would like that someone help me to understand why it is true.
"Let $A$ and $B$  be two linear, closed and densely defined operators such that $A\subset B$. Actually, since $A$ and $B$ have non empty resolvent sets cointaining all $i\eta$, then we have that $A=B$ holds."

Could anyone explain me why it is true? It is a general rule that if $A\subset B$ with non empty resolvent sets, then $A=B$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you taking $A\subset B$ to mean? $\operatorname{dom}(A)\subseteq\operatorname{dom}(B)$ and $Ax = Bx$ for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}(A)$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes, exactly.

Comment: Are you assuming they're both densely-defined or not?

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes, I edit right now.

Comment: It's not true that every closed, densely-defined linear operator has non-empty resolvent set, let alone contains the entire imaginary axis. Are you missing additional assumptions, e.g. self-adjointness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim:

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $A: D(A) \subseteq X \to X$ and $B: D(B) \subseteq X \to X$ be two closed linear operators.

Suppose that $\rho(A) \cap \rho(B) \neq \emptyset$, where $\rho(A)$ denotes the resolvent set of $A$.

Suppose that $D(A) \subseteq D(B)$ and $Au = Bu \; \forall u \in D(A)$. Then $A=B$.

Proof:

It is sufficient to show that $D(B) \subseteq D(A)$. 
Let $u \in D(B)$ and take $\lambda \in \rho(A) \cap \rho(B)$.

Define $v:= \lambda u - B u$ and $w := (\lambda I - A)^{-1}v$, so that $w \in D(A)$. 
Now observe that
$$
\lambda u - B u = v = (\lambda I -A)w = \lambda w - Aw = \lambda w- Bw, 
$$
so that 
$$
(\lambda I - B)(u-w) = 0 
$$
Since $\lambda I- B$ is injective, this implies that $u=w$, so that $u \in D(A)$.

In particular, regarding your question, the reason that $A=B$ is not that $A$ and $B$ have non-empty resolvent sets, but that their resolvent sets intersect.